# Move taskbar icons

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a WinForms application that opens more child windows with a different AppId, so they do not get grouped together in the taskbar. However, I would like to have the taskbar icon for the child windows next to the main WinForms application. Currently, they open at the end of the taskbar even if other programs opened in the meantime.

It then looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to influence where the taskbar icon of a window gets placed? Or can it be moved after it has been opened?

Comment: *"Is there any way to influence where the taskbar icon of a window gets placed?"* - Sure, by way of assigning an AppId. Beyond that it's up to the system's algorithm and user settings where icons get placed.

Comment: In other words, no, there is no way to accomplish what the OP is asking for.  You can control only which icons are grouped together, but the OS alone decides the ordering of icons and groups on the Taskbar itself.

Comment: Do you mean the icons in the system tray area? I'm not sure if you mean the order of icons in the taskbar or the order of icons in the tray.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I meant the order of icons in the taskbar, not system tray.

Comment: Related reading: [How do I customize how my application windows are grouped in the Taskbar?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813)